# why it is needed to pass auth_token in rails api for authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have rails app which serves as api as well using devise authetication, as far rails application is concerned authentication goes fine. But what in case of Rails Api, why I need to pass auth_token.Looks like passing auth_token need customizing of devise controller which seems to be a pain.Passing auth_token in request body using rest client allows me to signin via Post method but I dont find any response. Do I need to customize devise controllers ?

Need a help
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Do not want to append your `:auth_token` to the `POST/PUT` parameters on client side but send this token as a request header.

This is how you can do it-

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_filter :get_api_key
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  private
  def get_api_key
    if api_key = params[:api_key].blank? && request.headers["X-API-KEY"]
      params[:api_key] = api_key
    end
  end
end
```

And say your auth key for devise set us api key like-

```
config.token_authentication_key = :api_key
```

You can also use custom strategy that support for token HTTP header authentication in Devise like [this](https://gist.github.com/wojt-eu/4492569)

Comment: How api key is getting generated here?

Comment: api key is coming from request as a part of devise authentication.

Comment: Hey Sourabh, Thanks for your response.But request.headers["X-API-KEY"] troubling me, how that could be passed through rest client?.we have request body,response body and headers for-eg. content-type and Accept.I am responding auth_token for incoming request.